# present participle + relative pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns

I have two sentences and would like to combine them using a relative clause.

1. > Those who don't learn from the past are doomed to repeat previous mistakes.
2. > Knowing previous mistakes helps us to avoid repeating those mistakes.

Can I say:

> Those who don't learn from the past are doomed to repeat previous mistakes, knowing which helps us to avoid repeating those mistakes.

And is there some guide that I can read in regards to this topic?

Comment: I can't help noticing some sort of _wordiness_. I wouldn't go far after the first sentence because the idea is quite clear. You could finish your sentence and start a new one with a new subject and verb probably trying to capture a different aspect of the theme. Also if you'd like to continue, there is a shift in viewpoint that I don't find very attractive i.e. _Those_ and suddenly _us_.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions! But I still want to know, grammatically, if using a participle in front of a relative pronoun is acceptable. ("Knowing + which" as the subject of the clause?)

Comment: I see no problem with that grammatically _...repeat previous mistakes, learning lessons from which helps avoid making them in future_ that would be the least alteration of your original sentence though I believe you need to reconsider it. Also the participle might be considered by some as a _dangling structure_ since there is not a word that we can refer to as the agent of the participle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close to correct, but I would say there are two issues.

Firstly, consider whether *learning* is supposed to be a participial adjective or a gerund.  In the original sentence, it's a gerund, because it means **the act of knowing** helps us.

But when you stick that sentence on another sentence, it looks like a participial adjective, but then it doesn't make sense.  The participial clause usually applies to the subject of the sentence.  Consider "the birds flew by the window, chirping loudly" - clearly, the birds were chirping loudly, not the window.  Likewise, the subject of the first sentence is *those who don't learn from the past*, so if you just stick on a participial clause, it sounds like it applies to *those who don't learn*, which is not what you want.

Secondly, if you want to make a dependent clause, it should begin with a *subordinate conjunction* like **which**, so you were almost correct, but it should be "...previous mistakes, **which knowing** helps us..."

If you want to make a completely separate independent clause (effectively a separate sentence), it needs a coordinating conjunction like **and** or **but** or a semicolon.  For example:

"They are doomed to repeat previous mistakes, but knowing previous mistakes helps us..."
or
"They are doomed to repeat previous mistakes; knowing previous mistakes helps us..."

References:
 - [Clauses and phrases](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/gram_clauses_n_phrases.html)
 - [Subordinate conjunctions](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subordinate.html)

Answer (score 0):

stangdon is right in his first point and wrong in his second.  You CAN say "knowing which," although your particular sentence is quite clunky.

Comment: Hm, you might be right about that, now that I think about it.  (BTW, this should probably be a comment on my answer, rather than a separate answer.)